# Intellij Idea not showing up in apps and cannot add it to Favorites

Tags: 20.04, gnome, intellij

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 quite recently upgraded from 18.04.

I have desktop entry for Intellij Idea (manually installed in /opt/) from which I can launch it but for some reason it is not show in Apps list and also I am unable to pin it to the favorites.

Here is the content of the .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition
Icon=/opt/idea-IC-202.6397.94/bin/idea.svg
Exec="/opt/idea-IC-202.6397.94/bin/idea.sh" %f
Categories=Development;IDE;
```

I have tried to delete, recreate the desktop entry and re-login but to no avail.

What is needed in order such manually installed product to 1. get listed in the apps list and 2. be able to pin it to Favorites?

Comment: Where is that .desktop file located? You can create Desktop Entry from IntelliJ itself using option in title bar menu, eliminating manual work :)

Comment: I have already did that. Did not helped

Comment: The desktop entry seems fine to me. Did you reload shell after creating? Where is desktop entry located? Does `desktop-file-validate fileName.desktop` return anything (replace `fileName.desktop` with actuals)?

Comment: I've tried both in /usr/share/applicaitons (created by Intellij IDEA) and ~/Desktop (copy by me). desktop-file-validate do not show any problems. I've managed to make it to show in the applications list (edited /usr/share/applicaitons and removed some items) but still unable to add it to the Favorites.

Comment: IntelliJ creates in `~/.local/share/applications` unless you're creating system wide for all users. To add in favorites you can simply drap and drop to dock.

Comment: @Kulfy Yes, I tried both system wide and just for current user. Drag and drop does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Kulfy I found the problem: there was an old `.desktop` file for IntelliJ IDEA in `~/.local/share/applications` which contained invalid path (pointing to old version).

After deleting it and restarting GNOME shell using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and ruuning `restart`, I was able to add it to Favorites.

Answer (score 0):

1. first you can try to install from ubuntu software, eveeything should work correctly
2. try change:

Icon=/opt/idea-IC-202.6397.94/bin/idea.svg
to:

Icon=/opt/idea-IC-202.6397.94/bin/idea.png

Comment: I don't want to install the bundled package because it lags in updates. At the same time Intellij does not provide PPA...

Comment: Icon=/opt/idea-IC-202.6397.94/bin/idea.png

Comment: I am afraid it did not helped

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to download Jetbrains Toolbox and then manage these IDEs. It will be better and I prefer it. From updating to installing any Jetbrains IDE, it is simple. Just open the toolbox and install any IDE you want.